# Bootstrap 3 panels with text and images (with different background for the images)

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to implement 3 panels with text and images with a different background color for the images (darker) and another color for the text.

this is my current code which works for the desktop version of the website but breaks on mobile. 
At the moment the layout is IMAGE->IMAGE->IMAGE. Text->Text->Text and it should be IMAGE -> Text. Image -> Text. Image -> Text:

[current code](http://www.bootply.com/EqW24k131Z)

Comment: Hi Sarah.  Looks good so far! What exactly would you like it to look like?  Not sure what you mean by 'breaks'.  Thanks :)

Comment: Hey! At the moment the layout is IMAGE->IMAGE->IMAGE. Text->Text->Text and it should be IMAGE -> Text. Image -> Text. Image -> Text

Comment: Ah OK.  Your problem is that all of your images are in one row, then all the text in another.  I'll pop a bit of example code in as an answer to get you started.

Comment: Also it's worth checking this link out to help with questions here in the future.  Easy mistake to make though, good luck! :)  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as per my comment, you need to include both your image and text into a column, then all three columns into a row.  Something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div><img src="#"></div>
    <div>Some text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div><img src="#"></div>
    <div>Some text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div><img src="#"></div>
    <div>Some text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You should check out the bootstrap site for guidance on using their grid layout :)

Answer (score 0):

In bootstarp to using panels you must use panel codes
you can see the bootstrap panels here [Bootstrap Panels](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <img src="#">
                <p>text Here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <img src="#">
                <p>text Here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <img src="#">
                <p>text Here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Automatically all three columns put in the one row if you want use different column grid you must the another div tag to specify the grids

also panels have the panel title class but I used panel heading class you can use panel title if you want